# Applying the change of list at the start of a function

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to create a word search generator by using list within list. However, one of the things that I've been trying to do is that the list must preserve the word that it append before rather than start a blank list. The method that I did was to simply call on a previous function for this.

```
initial= list()
def board ():
    inital = add()
    test = list()
    for a in range(5):
        test.append(a)
    initial = test.copy()
    return initial
def add():
    initial = board()
    for a in range(5,10):
        initial.append(a)
    initial = initial.copy()
    return initial
initial = add()
inital = board()
print(initial)
```

When I tried running it in the terminal, an error message appeared saying that the maximum recursion depth has exceeded. What does this means and how do I achieve the goal (having a list that prints 5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4)?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but `add` calls `board` and `board` immediately calls `add`, which is an infinite recursive loop. Can you clarify what these functions are _supposed_ to do?

Comment: Hmm, `add()` calls `board()` which calls `add()` again... That leads to an infinite recursion immediately. You need an abort condition in at least one of them.

Comment: Separately, you have two lists called `inital` and `initial` which is very confusing, and they're being accessed as globals instead of being passed between functions which makes the intended control flow very hard to follow as well.